# Consulta SQL para una funcion

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

buenas tardes, debo hacer una función que retorne un valor numérico. Ese valor numérico debe ser 1 si la consulta devuelve un valor y 0 en caso de que no. Para ponerlos en contexto:

> 1- Una persona tiene un número de sorteo

> 2- Una persona tiene un título

Para saber el número de sorteo, debo buscarlo en base a su número de título, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @numSorteo AS FLOAT
SET @numSorteo = (SELECT numeroSorteo
                  FROM tablaB
                  WHERE titulo = 117156) --El valor obtenido es 784
```

Ahora, tenemos una tabla con las fechas de vencimientos de cada factura emitida para ello realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
DECLARE @vencCuotas AS SMALLDATETIME
SET @vencCuotas = (SELECT MAX(Vencimiento) FROM VencimientoCuotas) --Eso devuelve: 2022-09-23 00:00:00
```

Ahora, necesito saber cuál es la última factura paga de esa persona por lo que hago lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @ultFechaVencimientoPaga AS SMALLDATETIME
SET @ultFechaVencimientoPaga = (SELECT MAX(FechaVencimiento) 
                                FROM TablaA taa
                                    INNER JOIN TablaB tab
                                        ON taa.COD= tab.COD 
                                WHERE fechaPago IS NOT NULL 
                                    AND TITULO = @titulo)-- Eso me devuelve: 2021-10-29 00:00:00
```

Ahora, lo que quiero saber es si ese número salió dentro de las **fechas**: `@ultFechaVencimientoPaga` y `@vencCuotas` realizando lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @valorSorteo AS INT
SET @valorSorteo = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM TablaSorteo
                    WHERE Nro1= @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro2 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro3 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro4 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro5 = @numSorteo
                        AND FechaSorteoRealizado
                            BETWEEN @ultFechaVencimientoPaga AND @vencCuotas)
```

Ahora, el problema con esto es que el resultado es dos:

```
SELECT @valorSorteo 'Valor contador sorteo'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ese valor no está bien ya que en ese rango de fechas establecido me debe traer un solo valor porque entre **2021-10-29 y 2022-09-23** solo ha salido una vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para controlar si los valores de las fechas son los correctos, hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT @vencCuotas 'Valor del último vencimiento actual'
SELECT @ultFechaVencimientoPaga 'Valor de la última cuota pagada'
SELECT @valorSorteo 'Valor contador sorteo'
```

Y eso me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede decir en dónde está mi error? Porque no lo estaría viendo

Comment: FechaSorteoRealizado es lo mismo que fechasorteo?

Comment: Sip, sino que una es una db de prueba y la otra es la de desarrollo pero si son lo mismo @gbianchi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error parece ser porque no estás usando paréntesis y primero se evaluan los AND y luego los OR. Por lo tanto tu condición de rango de fechas solo aplica para la comparación con el último número. Agrupando todas las comparaciones del número de sorteo con un paréntesis puedes solucionar el error.

```
DECLARE @valorSorteo AS INT
SET @valorSorteo = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM TablaSorteo
                    WHERE (Nro1= @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro2 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro3 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro4 = @numSorteo 
                        OR Nro5 = @numSorteo)
                        AND FechaSorteoRealizado
                            BETWEEN @ultFechaVencimientoPaga AND @vencCuotas)
```

Una opción más sencilla, puede ser usar IN, aunque sea de forma contraria a como se usa comunmente.

```
DECLARE @valorSorteo AS INT
SET @valorSorteo = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM TablaSorteo
                    WHERE @numSorteo IN( Nro1, Nro2, Nro3, Nro4, Nro5)
                      AND FechaSorteoRealizado BETWEEN @ultFechaVencimientoPaga AND @vencCuotas)
```

Comment: Waw, no sabía que se podían usar así los `IN` es un dato nuevo a tener en cuenta. 
Como tal, la modificación que sugieres ha sido correcta ya que funciona como preciso, muchas gracias